# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in jquery autocomplete 1.10 version

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
Here is my code to implement autocomplete of jquery ui 1.10 on 8 comboboxes on my page. i am getting maximum call stack size exceeding.
```

doing some googling i came to know that reason behind
 error in infinte call to some functions in code. 
i have commented one by one event like focus, select, change to see which event is throughing multiple call in my code. but event after commenting 
all the events bug still comes.this bug hangs firefox browser 
for some time. thanks for you interest in helping to solve this problem.

```
    $(function(){

$("input[name^='TextRogue'],input[name^='TextBrand']").each(function(index,value){

 $(this).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: users,

  focus: function( event, ui ) {
    $(this).val( ui.item.LoginID);
    return false;
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) { 

    var Name=ui.item.FirstName;
    if(ui.item.LastName  && ui.item.LastName!='')
    {
        Name+=" "+ui.item.LastName;
    }
    $(this).val( ui.item.LoginID+" ("+Name+")" );
    var name= $(this).attr('name');
    var prefix='';
    if(name.lastIndexOf('Rogue')!=-1)
    {
        prefix='Rogue';
    }
    else
    {
        prefix='Brand';
    }
    var underscore_index=name.lastIndexOf('_');
    var suffix=name.substr(underscore_index);
    $("#"+prefix+suffix).val( ui.item.UserID );  
   // code remove from here..

    return false;
  },
  source: function (request, response) {
       // var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        var matching = $.grep(users, function (value) {
            var LoginID = value.LoginID;
            var Email = value.Email;

            return matcher.test(LoginID) || matcher.test(Email);
        });
        response(matching);
    },
  change: function(event,ui){  if(!ui.item){  
                // The item selected from the menu, if any. Otherwise the property is null
                //so clear the item for force selection
                $(this).val("");
                // also clear the hidden field containing values related to previous selection
                var name= $(this).attr('name');
                var prefix='';
                if(name.lastIndexOf('Rogue')!=-1)
                {
                    prefix='Rogue';
                }
                else
                {
                    prefix='Brand';
                }
                var underscore_index=name.lastIndexOf('_');
                var suffix=name.substr(underscore_index);
                $("#"+prefix+suffix).val('');
            }

    }
    })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var Name=item.FirstName;
        if(item.LastName  && item.LastName!='')
        {
            Name+=" "+item.LastName;
        }
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.LoginID +" ("+Name+")<br><span style='font-size:12px;'>" + item.Email + "</span></a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };

    });
    fillSuggestedBrand();
    fillSuggestedRogue();

  });
```

Comment: i figured out that problem is that i am dynamically adding 80,000 users as source to jquery autocomplete.if i have only few users like 10 as assigned to users javascript variable then there are no such errors. but later as site grows i ll be having lakhs of users. problem ll come then.. any help and direction on what to do will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solved,just change minLength: 0 option to greater than 0 in integers and it works fine as it doesn't fire autocomplete request when input box is emptied by deleting characters from input box one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Bug is solved now,just change minLength: 0 option to greater than 0 in integers and it works fine as it doesn't fire autocomplete request when input box is emptied by deleting characters from input box one by one.

Comment: positive inteeger numbers, mention 1 or the minimum length u want to trigger auto complete feature.